# MongoDB csv skip missing keys/values

Tags: mongodb, csv, pymongo, export-to-csv

I got a large DB with around 1mil entries. I'm using Pymongo to convert it to CSV. The problem is, some of the key/value pairs are missing or are placed in wrong order in the DB.

This results in CSV file fields being shifted.

**DB**

```
[
  {
    "_id": "123abc",
    "device": 
    {
      "Chanel": "1",
      "Vendror": "undefined",
      "first_seen": "1611606675",
      "last_seen": "1612606695",
    },
    {
      "Chanel": "1",
      "first_seen": "1612342635",
      "Vendror": "abc",
      "last_seen": "1631606928",
    },
    {
      "Chanel": "1",
      "first_seen": "1612342635",
      "Vendror": "abc"
    }, 
  }
]
```

**TRIED**
**1.** Hardcoding headers, compare to key and write value. If key not existent write value 'N/A'

```
with open(fn, 'w', encoding="utf-8") as wf:
    
            header = ['_id', 'Chanel', 'Vendor', 'first_seen', 'last_seen']
            for key in header:
                write_file.write(key + ',')
   
            write_file.write('\n')

            #timeframe is a list of all documents within certain timeframe
            for batch in timeframe:    
                for data_items in batch['device']:
     
                    
                    for key, value in data_items.items():
                        if key not in header:
                           wf.write('NA')

                        else:
                            value = str(value)
                            value = value.replace(',', '-')
                            write_file.write(f'{value},')

                    wf.write('\n')
            wf.write('\n')
                    
        return fn
```

**2.** Tried converting to json and use Pandas to convert json to CSV - same issue

**EXPECTED OUTPUT**

```
_id    | Chanel |   Vendor  | first_seen | last_seen
------------------------------------------------------
123abc |   1    | undefined | 1611606675 | 1612606695
------------------------------------------------------
123abc |   1    | undefined | 1612342635 | 1631606928
------------------------------------------------------
123abc |   1    | undefined | 1612342635 | N/A
------------------------------------------------------
```

**ACTUAL OUTPUT**

```
_id    | Chanel |   Vendor  | first_seen | last_seen
------------------------------------------------------
123abc |   1    | undefined | 1611606675 | 1612606695
------------------------------------------------------
123abc |   1    | 1612342635| undefined  | 1631606928
------------------------------------------------------
123abc |   1    | 1612342635 | undefined |
------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Please show us your code. Be aware, by default the fields do not have any order. You may need to put a `sort` operation in your code.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit edited.
I tried doing that with json to csv, however it refuses to write "N/A" in either of the methods

Comment: I am not familiar with python at all, but maybe something like `for key in OrderedDict(header):` and `for key, value in OrderedDict(data_items.items()):`